# Apply new 'bold' highlight rule to all format, preserve color

Tags: syntax-highlighting

Since I usually use a blank line to denote start of a new codeblock (function, class, etc.)
I defined the following syntax rule.

The intent is to make the first line of a code block standout.

While the pattern works, It replaces the color coding of the individual keywords in the line with a white color. What is the best way to ensure that the color is retained?

```
syntax region BlankLine start='^\s*$' end='^\s*\S.*'
highlight BlankLine ctermbg=NONE ctermfg=NONE cterm=underline,bold
"highlight BlankLine cterm=underline,bold
```

e.g. for the code below
[image: Snapshot of code showing normal highlight, desired highlight and actual highlight]

Comment: You are talking about which syntax rules have priority? Have you read `:h syn-priority`?

Comment: I am looking for "merging" syntax rules rather than applying one out of many 

e.g. if I have
```

def function_name():
```
I want the 'def' keyword to have its highlight(fg=yellow in my case) defined in the python syntaxfile + I want the line to be bold and underlined as defined above.

Comment: Syntax items do not "merge". They do "contain", "extend" and "overlap" each other. You have to stick to `:match`, `matchadd()` and such.

Comment: Ah, that's what you mean by "preserve color" then, I guess.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! It might be helpful if you [edit] and include some examples of what you're trying to accomplish and what's not working

Comment: I have added an image which shows 
1. Normal Behavior.
2. Desired behavior
3. Resultant behavioor

Comment: @matt Thanks, replacing the syntax region.... by "match  BlankLine /^\s*\n.*/ " did the trick. If you can submit it as an answer I will accept and close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different Syntax matches never combine highlighting. There's always one that wins, see `:h :syn-priority`, `:h :syn-contains` etc.

You need `:h :match` instead:

```
hi VSpace cterm=standout gui=standout
match VSpace /^\s*\n.*/
```